# Refresh an activity a certain number of times

Tags: android

Hello I would like to refresh an activity 3 times, and after 3 times, it would start another activity.

The problem I have with my code is that it will always refresh even if it reaches 3 times.

Can you help me ? Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by refresh? Do you mean recreate activity or refresh UI?

Comment: If you tell your requirement, then we can tell the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you start activity, then your `currentCalculIndex` gets initial value. You have to hold its value some how.

A solution can be following.

Replace

> ```
> Intent intent1 = getIntent();
> finish();
> startActivity(intent1);
> ```

with

```
int count = getIntent().getIntExtra("count", 0);
startActivity(getIntent().putExtra("count", ++count));
finish();
```

and Replace

> ```
> currentCalculIndex ++;
> if(currentCalculIndex > 3) {
> ```

with this

```
if(getIntent().getIntExtra("count", 0) > 3) {
}
```

Comment: thank you. but where should I write those lines ?

startActivity(getIntent().putExtra("count", ++getIntent().getIntExtra("count", 0))); says its a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Declare **currentCalculIndex**  as a global variable with initial value 0

int currentCalculIndex   = 0;

//your refersh Method --

```
currentCalculIndex ++;
        if(currentCalculIndex > 3) {

            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long time = endTime - startTime;

            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(time), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //go to highscores
            Intent intent = new Intent(Jeu.this, HighScores.class);
            intent.putExtra("time", String.valueOf(time));
            startActivity(intent);

            return;
        }else{

        Toast.makeText(this, "Bravo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent1);

        /////////////////////////////////
        }
```